# Firebase .keepSynced best practices

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

1. Where is the best place to put a .keepSynced(true) on a Firebase ref? This particular ref points to data that won't change much but that I need for almost all of my app's view controllers.
2. Do I need an event listener for this ref if I set .keepSynced to true?

Comment: #1. depends on your use-case. It's not answerable without knowing all your use-cases and too broad for Stack Overflow. #2. you'll eventually need a listener to read the data. But the data will be synchronized even when there's no listener attached.